# I have an empty function that's deregistering my controllers in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angularjs 1.6.3, I have a controller like this:

```
'use strict';

var ngnControllers = angular.module('ngnControllers');
ngnControllers.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http',
    function TestCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {
        console.log("Before defining $scope.play()");
        $scope.play() = function() {

        };
        console.log("After defining $scope.play()");
    }
]);
```

I copied the `$scope.play()` function from another controller where it was having the same effect:

When it is not commented out, I get a message saying that the controller is not registered, but that's all. When it is commented out everything works fine.

I am at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind. It took writing out again to see what was right in front of me.

Answer (score 1):

Because your function declaration syntax is wrong and as a result is throwing an error. The error gets caught internally and simply causes the controller registration to fail

Change:

```
$scope.play() = function() {
```

To

```
$scope.play = function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have empty dependencies added to your module,

```
var ngnControllers = angular.module('ngnControllers',[]);
```

Comment: Module must already be declared or commenting out the improper code wouldn't work either